# How to pass image to AWS SageMaker endpoint

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I need to use the [WireframeToCode](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-7y6xdiukxucr2) model from the AWS Marketplace, I used Nodejs to read and send the file data to the model like this:

```
var sageMakerRuntime = new AWS.SageMakerRuntime();

var bitmap = fs.readFileSync("sample.jpeg", "utf8");
var buffer = new Buffer.from(bitmap, "base64");

var params = {
  Body: buffer.toJSON(),
  EndpointName: "wireframe-to-code",
  Accept: "image/jpeg",
  ContentType: "application/json"
};

sageMakerRuntime.invokeEndpoint(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
  else console.log(data);
});
```

but i get this error:

> message: 'Expected params.Body to be a string, Buffer, Stream, Blob,
>   or typed array object',   code: 'InvalidParameterType',   time:
>   2020-03-30T11:06:27.535Z

From the documentation, the supported content type for input is  `image/jpeg` output is `application/json`.

when I try to convert the Body to a string like this: `JSON.stringify(buffer.toJSON())` I get this error:

> Received client error (415) from model with message "This predictor
>   only supports JSON formatted data"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to pass in bitmap and change `ContentType` to `"image/jpeg"`

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const fs = require("fs");

const sageMakerRuntime = new AWS.SageMakerRuntime({
  region: "us-east-1",
  accessKeyId: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
  secretAccessKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
});

const bitmap = fs.readFileSync("sample.jpeg");

var params = {
  Body: bitmap,
  EndpointName: "wireframe-to-code",
  ContentType: "image/jpeg"
};

sageMakerRuntime.invokeEndpoint(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack);
  } else {
    responseData = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(data.Body).toString());
    console.log(responseData);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So I think that you need to amend the payload that you're passing to `invokeEndpoint`

The documentation suggests that while the payload needs to be JSON, the body needs to be a buffer in this case and it will encode to base64 for free.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SageMakerRuntime.html#invokeEndpoint-property

```
const fs = require('fs')

const sageMakerRuntime = new AWS.SageMakerRuntime()

const bitmap = fs.readFileSync('sample.jpeg', 'utf8')
const buffer = new Buffer.from(bitmap)

const params = {
    Body: buffer, //Buffer, Typed Array, Blob, String
    EndpointName: 'wireframe-to-code',
    Accept: 'image/jpeg', //The desired MIME type of the inference in the response
    ContentType: 'image/jpeg', //MIME type of body
}

sageMakerRuntime.invokeEndpoint(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack)
    else console.log(data)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer to make it work I had to pass in the bitmap and change `ContentType` to `"image/jpeg"`